# Changing the default action when clicking on links in Terminal.app

Tags: osx-mavericks, terminal.app

Previously I've been able to open links just by clicking them on Terminal.app. After updating my OSX, the terminal now gives Quick Look as default option for links. Is there any way to disable Quick Look on Terminal.app or change the order of actions on the context menu so that Open URL would be first option again?

Comment: slightly stupid idea, but, could you use the OS X 10.8.5 terminal on OS X 10.9?

Comment: Just curious: is Quick Look really the default for you? Or just the first in the context menu, but *not* triggered when just clicking the link? I see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pwpwO.png) when right-clicking in Bash, while a regular click has no effect.

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer to stick with terminal rather than using iterm2?

Comment: I prefer to stick with default apps if possible as I often need to use random Macs and don't really want to install any apps on them if possible.

So far the best workaround seems to be CMD clicking the link, not ideal, but also not as frustrating as the Quick Look opening it into a browser instance I cannot configure (adblock, noscript etc)

Answer (score 1):

I am on OSX 10.10.2 and by holding CMD and double-clicking the link it opens in Chrome.

`echo "http://www.google.com"`

Answer (score 0):

For example, let’s say you wanted to change the system’s default text editor. Run the following command in a terminal:

sudo update-alternatives –config editor